# Laravel doctrine translatable

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm, doctrine, translation

i'm using laravel 5.4 and laravel-doctrine/orm:1.3.*

and have some problems with translatable package. 
The problem is, that listener not listening application locale, for example
 my class

```
class Article implements Translatable
{
 ...
/**
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 * @ORM\Column(length=128)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Locale
 */
private $locale;



public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;
}

public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;
}

public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

public function setTranslatableLocale($locale)
{
    $this->locale = $locale;
}
}
```

i insert entity data as in example

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('Gedmo\\Translatable\\Entity\\Translation');

$article = new Article();
$article->setTitle('My article en');
$article->setContent('content en');

$repository->translate($article, 'title', 'de', 'my article de')
    ->translate($article, 'content', 'de', 'content de')
    ->translate($article, 'title', 'ru', 'my article ru')
    ->translate($article, 'content', 'ru', 'content ru')
;

$em->persist($article);
$em->flush();
```

When my site at en locale, that's ok, but when i switch locale in config to 'ru', it load en locale, not ru.

it works only when i make something like this

```
$article->setTranslatableLocale('ru');
$this->em->refresh($article);
```

Comment: Could you found any solution? I'm facing with the same issue. Also when I update the entity with the default locale, it is not loading the updated locale content.

Comment: I just write my own translatable.

1) Create Entity Article
2) Create Entity ArticleDescription with translatable fields and locale.
3) Join table in repository and get translated values.